# How to get list of suppliers with most orders first

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

**Relationship**

`Supplier` -> one to many relationship with `orders`

```
| suppliers                             |
| ----------                            |
| id | name | archived (bool) | user_id |

| orders                        |
| ----------------              |
| id | supplier_id | creator_id |
```

**Expectation**

Now, I want to get list of popular `suppliers` for given `supplier.user_id` and `orders.creator_id` and that `supplier` should not be `archived` (please find expected result at the end of the question).

Here is what i want:

- Suppliers ORDER BY maximum(count(orders.supplier_id))
- Where supplier.archived = false
- Where supplier.user_id = 2
- where orders.creator_id = 1

**Unsuccessful Attampt**

Here is my unsuccessful attampt, I am not sure how to add suppliers conditions in this query.

```
  select supplier_id, COUNT(*) as count_suppliers 
  from orders 
  where creator_id = 2
  group by orders.supplier_id
  order by count_suppliers desc
```

**So here is what I want**

```
suppliers

| id  | user_id | archived |
| --- | ---------  | -------  |
| 1   | 2          | false    |
| 2   | 2          | false    |
| 3   | 2          | false    |
| 4   | 2          | false    |
| 5   | 2          | true     |

orders

| id | creator_id | supplier_id  |
| -- | ---------  | ------------ |
| 1  | 1          | 1            |
| 2  | 1          | 1            |
| 3  | 1          | 1            |
| 4  | 1          | 1            |
| 5  | 1          | 2            |
| 6  | 1          | 2            |
| 7  | 1          | 3            |
| 8  | 1          | 4            |
| 9  | 1          | 4            |
| 10 | 1          | 4            |
| 11 | 1          | 5            |

expected output

| supplier_id | supplier_count |
| 1           | 4              |
| 4           | 3              |
| 2           | 2              |
| 3           | 1              |
```

**SOLUTION**

So finally by reference to Vamsi's answer, here you can find both RAW SQL version and ActiveRecord (Rails) version of solution to this problem:

`RAW SQL VERSION`

```
SELECT o.supplier_id, COUNT(*) AS count_suppliers 
FROM suppliers s
JOIN orders o ON s.id=o.supplier_id
WHERE s.user_id=2 
AND s.archived=FALSE
AND o.creator_id=2
GROUP BY o.supplier_id
ORDER BY count_suppliers DESC
LIMIT 5
```

`ActiveRecord (Rails) Version`

```
Supplier
  .joins(:orders)
  .where(user_id: 2, archived: false, orders: { creator_id: 2 })
  .group("orders.supplier_id")
  .order("count_all DESC")
  .limit(limit)
  .count
```

Comment: First figure out which RBDMS you're using. Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I was missing the `JOIN` part. Vamsi Prabhala's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `join` the tables and count.

```
select p.supplier_id, COUNT(*) as count_suppliers 
from purchase_orders p
join suppliers s on s.id=p.supplier_id
where s.user_id=2 and p.creator_id=1 and s.archived='False'
group by p.supplier_id
order by count_suppliers desc
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks like I was missing the join part, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 supplier_id, COUNT(*) as count_suppliers 
from purchase_orders 
where orders.creator_id = 1
And supplier.archived = false
And supplier.user_id = 2
group by purchase_orders.supplier_id
order by COUNT(*) desc
```

Comment: This looks like a SQL Server query, I don't think that'll work in either MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Comment: Yes, there is no reference to orders or supplier anywhere, you are missing `JOIN` in the query

Comment: Vamsi's answer is working as expected.